# When using XPath to find variable, taking only a piece of that variable

Tags: xpath, tokenize

I am new to XPath.  I am writing a code to grab all the 3 digit numbers from a page.  They are not constant, varying between 105, 515, and 320.  I want two be able to tokenize these numbers into two separate pieces...

i would love to be able to grab the first digit in one X-path expression
and 
the second two digits in a second X-Path expression

on doing my research I came across that you couldn't tokenize with 'zero value,'  but is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**It seems to me that the question is actually about the possible ways to *split* a 3-digit number into two strings**, the first containing the first digit and the second containing the remaining two digits.

**Here is one possible solution**:

**The following XPath expression when evaluated produces a string containing the first digit of a number $vNum** (in an actual XPath expression, substitute $vNum with the XPath expression that produces this value):

```
  substring($vNum, 1, 1)
```

**The following XPath expression when evaluated produces a string containing the last two digits of a 3-digit number $vNum** (in an actual XPath expression, substitute $vNum with the XPath expression that produces this value):

```
  substring($vNum, 2)
```

**In case if we are not sure about the number of digits** $vNum has, **the following XPath expression when evaluated produces a string containing the two digits that immediately follow the first digit of a 3+ digit number** $vNum (in an actual XPath expression, substitute $vNum with the XPath expression that produces this value):

```
  substring($vNum, 2, 2)
```

And lastly, **if we again don't know the exact number of digits, but want to get the last two of them, the following XPath expression when evaluated produces a string containing the two digits at the end of a 2+ digit number $vNum** (in an actual XPath expression, substitute $vNum with the XPath expression that produces this value):

```
 substring($vNum, string-length($vNum) - 1)
```